# как найти все экземпляры регулярного выражения в строке на с++?

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, stl

Есть вот такой код, мне нужно найти все выражения по типу th.f=/sdaasd/sadas/asd.php, в строке str их содержится 3. Проблема в том, что этот код помещает в переменную результ только первое подобное выражение, как это исправить?

```
int main()
{
    ConeConfigParser("/home/anton/regtest", WS);
    std::string str = "xdZasdSA SADSAD SADSDSA SAD th.f=/sdaasd/sadas/asd.php th.f=/sdsdaaasd/sadas/asd.txt th.f=/sdaasdsad/sadas/asd.pyton";
    std::cmatch result;
    std::regex regular("([\\w\\d-\.]+[\\s]*=[\\w/\.]+)"
                      );
    if (std::regex_search(str.c_str(), result, regular))
        std::cout << true << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
        std::cout << result[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если вы собираетесь разбирать *настоящие* URL-запросы (в стандарте RFC 3986), то регулярное выражение описанное в статье Википедии [URI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI) вот такое -- `^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?`

Comment: @avp, в данном случае это не для url, но все равно спасибо. Но проблему это не решает

Comment: правильно ли я вас понимаю: из `/home/anton/regtest` вам нужно получить `{"home", "anton", "regtest"}`?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, нет. Мне требуется получить все выражение целиком th.f=/sdaasd/sadas/asd.php, но не одно, а все выражения такого типа в строке, в данном примере их 3, но программа выдает одно, только первое

Comment: Если нужны все `name=value`,  и пробелов и внутри них нет, то я бы просто в цикле искал `=`, а потом выбирал name,value слева и справа. Просто  и надежно (регулярки внутри программ -- зло)

Comment: @avp, проблема в том, что между name и value может быть неопределенное количество пробелов

Comment: Разве это проблема? Пропустите их в цикле